# Missing folder on iCloud.com

Tags: icloud

I have a Sketch folder on Finder that I've been saving files to. I can't find/access it on iCloud.com. Does anyone have any insights on why? Only found people who have had the opposite problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are they in sync ? You can test by coping some file in another folder and wait for it appear on iCloud. Also, replacing this folder with a new one ( with all the data) with the same name should get things working .. “why” this happens is an interesting question.

Comment: I saw your iCloud storage is full. Did you try to free up and re-sync your iCloud again?